# how to replace the content of the parent control from child user control in code behind

Tags: wpf

I am writing something in the code behind of auditInventoryViews:SchedulerView user control to replace the content of the parent contentControl "DSViewContentControl"
    I tried with "this.content" but it only replace the content of the current user control and other content still remain the in the usercontrol.

So thing is how can I replace the content of the parent control from child in code behind.

Sample code for example

```
<UserControl>
<ContentControl x:Name="DSViewContentControl" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- region scheduler -->
         <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="40,5,0,0">
          some content
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="40,5,0,0">
        <auditInventoryViews:SchedulerView/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference parent control from child through `Parent` property. For example to get `DSViewContentControl` from `SchedulerView` code-behind :

```
StackPanel parentStackpnl = (StackPanel)this.Parent;
Grid grandParentGrid = (Grid)parentStackpnl.Parent;
ContentControl DSViewContentControl = (ContentControl)grandParentGrid.Parent;
//at this point doing operation on DSViewContentControl is straightforward
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Your tried with your approach and able to get parent content control using
      ContentControl DSViewContentControl = (ContentControl)(((Grid)((StackPanel)this.Parent).Parent).Parent);